# How to extract a path if it contains a folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, path

Lets say some paths like these:

```
C:/Test/path_i_need/test2/test3/test4
C:/Test/test2/path_i_need/test3
C:/Test/test2/test3/path_i_need/test4
```

How I can extract the path that i need in each of the scenarios using python, for example:

```
C:/Test/path_i_need
C:/Test/test2/path_i_need
C:/Test/test2/test3/path_i_need
```

So basically i don't know how many sub folder are before the path_i_need or after it, I only need that path, i dont care whats after.

Comment: you will definitely need to use the OS package

Comment: what criteria will dictate what paths you need?

Comment: so whats special about path_ineed? for ex. is it like the project root directory or something else?

Comment: Check out [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) from the standard libraries. `Path` objects can be used for many path manipulations.

Comment: Are you literally looking for a path component called "path_i_need"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do a DFS ([depth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search)) from the root directory until you find all the paths you're looking for:

```py
from os import listdir, path

ROOT_DIR = "./example"
FLAG = "example1"

found_dirs = []

def find_dirs(p):
  subdirs = listdir(p)
  for subdir in subdirs:
    curdir = path.join(p, subdir)
    if subdir == FLAG:
      found_dirs.append(curdir)
    elsif path.isdir(curdir):
      find_dirs(curdir)

find_dirs(ROOT_DIR)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, without using `os` module or any imports:

```py
paths = """
C:/Test/path_i_need/test2/test3/test4
C:/Test/test2/path_i_need/test3
C:/Test/test2/test3/path_i_need/test4
""".strip().split('\n')

need_this_path = 'path_i_need'

len_that_which_i_need = len(need_this_path)

extracted_paths = [p[:p.index(need_this_path) + len_that_which_i_need] for p in paths]
print(*extracted_paths, sep='\n')
```

Outputs:

```
C:/Test/path_i_need
C:/Test/test2/path_i_need
C:/Test/test2/test3/path_i_need
```